# Is every double covering map regular?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

As in the title, does a double covering map (i.e. a covering map for which every preimage consists of two points) have to be regular (i.e. the image of the fundamental group is a normal subgroup of the fundamental group of the image space)?

The only examples of double-covering maps i can think of are very simple ones for which the push forward of the fundamental group is trivial or abelian, in such a case this is obviously true. I have a suspicion though that in general this is false. What are some intuitive counterexamples for this? Or maybe I'm wrong, in which case how would the proof of this fact go?

Comment: Hint: What do you know about the index of the subgroup corresponding to a double covering?

Comment: @LeeMosher Oooooh, the index has to be 2 right? In that case the theorem  would be true.

Comment: > _"push forward of the fundamental group is trivial or abelian, in such a case this is obviously true"_ . Just because a subgroup is abelian doesn't mean that it is normal. For example $SO(3)$ which is simple, contains a copy of $SO(2)$ which is abelian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was essentially given in the comments already.

**Proposition.** Let $E$ be a *path-connected* topological space and let $B$ be a topological space. If a (surjective) covering $p\colon E\rightarrow B$ is $2$-sheeted, then it is regular.

*Proof.* Recall that the degree of the path-connected covering $p$ is given by the index of the subgroup $p_\ast(\pi_1(E))$ in $\pi_1(B)$. See Proposition 1.32 in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* for a proof. As usual, $p_\ast$ denotes the induced homomorphism $\pi_1(E)\rightarrow \pi_1(B)$. Since subgroups of index two are normal, we thus have that $p_\ast(\pi_1(E))$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(B)$. Thus, the covering $p\colon E\rightarrow B$ is regular.